# How to create navigation bar in EXTJS 4.1.?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

EXTJS 4.1
I have two locking grids in my panel.
**How to create a side navigation bar in EXTJS 4.1.** with two options such that on clicking first option first locking grid is displayed and on clicking other option ,the second locking grid is created.

My current code is like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title>       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.define('Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager', {

    requires: ['Ext.ProgressBar'],
    /**
     * @cfg {Number} width
     * <p>The default progress bar width.  Default is 225.</p>
    */
    width   : 225,
    /**
     * @cfg {String} defaultText
    * <p>The text to display while the store is loading.  Default is 'Loading...'</p>
     */
    defaultText    : 'Loading...',
    /**
     * @cfg {Object} defaultAnimCfg
     * <p>A {@link Ext.fx.Anim Ext.fx.Anim} configuration object.</p>
     */
    defaultAnimCfg : {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'bounceOut' 
    },  

    /**
     * Creates new ProgressBarPager.
     * @param {Object} config Configuration options
     */
    constructor : function(config) {
        if (config) {
            Ext.apply(this, config);
        }
    },
    //public
    init : function (parent) {
        var displayItem;
        if (parent.displayInfo) {
            this.parent = parent;

            displayItem = parent.child("#displayItem");
            if (displayItem) {
                parent.remove(displayItem, true);
            }

            this.progressBar = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar', {
                text    : this.defaultText,
                width   : this.width,
                animate : this.defaultAnimCfg,
                style: {
                    cursor: 'pointer'
                },
                listeners: {
                    el: {
                        scope: this,
                        click: this.handleProgressBarClick
                    }
                }
            });

            parent.displayItem = this.progressBar;

            parent.add(parent.displayItem);
            Ext.apply(parent, this.parentOverrides);
        }
    },
    // private
    // This method handles the click for the progress bar
    handleProgressBarClick : function(e){
        var parent = this.parent,
            displayItem = parent.displayItem,
            box = this.progressBar.getBox(),
            xy = e.getXY(),
            position = xy[0]- box.x,
            pages = Math.ceil(parent.store.getTotalCount() / parent.pageSize),
            newPage = Math.max(Math.ceil(position / (displayItem.width / pages)), 1);

        parent.store.loadPage(newPage);
    },

    // private, overriddes
    parentOverrides  : {
        // private
        // This method updates the information via the progress bar.
        updateInfo : function(){
            if(this.displayItem){
                var count = this.store.getCount(),
                    pageData = this.getPageData(),
                    message = count === 0 ?
                    this.emptyMsg :
                    Ext.String.format(
                        this.displayMsg,
                        pageData.fromRecord, pageData.toRecord, this.store.getTotalCount()
                    ),
                    percentage = pageData.pageCount > 0 ? (pageData.currentPage / pageData.pageCount) : 0;

                this.displayItem.updateProgress(percentage, message, this.animate || this.defaultAnimConfig);
            }
        }
    }
});


Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.QuickTips.init()

    // sample static data for the store
    var myData = [
        ['3m Co',                               71.72, 0.02,  0.03,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Alcoa Inc',                           29.01, 0.42,  1.47,  '9/1 12:00am'],
        ['Altria Group Inc',                    83.81, 0.28,  0.34,  '9/1 12:00am']];


    /**
     * Custom function used for column renderer
     * @param {Object} val
     */
    function change(val) {
        if (val > 0) {
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '</span>';
        } else if (val < 0) {
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }

    /**
     * Custom function used for column renderer
     * @param {Object} val
     */
    function pctChange(val) {
        if (val > 0) {
            return '<span style="color:green;">' + val + '%</span>';
        } else if (val < 0) {
            return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '%</span>';
        }
        return val;
    }

    // create the data store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        autoLoad: false,
        pageSize : 5,
        fields: [
           {name: 'company'},
           {name: 'price',      type: 'float'},
           {name: 'change',     type: 'float'},
           {name: 'pctChange',  type: 'float'},
           {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'}
        ],
        data: myData,
         proxy: {
                    type: 'memory',
                    enablePaging: true,
                    data: myData
                }
    });

     store.load({
    params: {
        // specify params for the first page load if using paging
        start: 0,          
        limit: 5,

    }
});

    // create the Grid
    var grid1 = {
          buffered: true,
   loadMask: true,
   style: 'border: solid Red 2px',
        xtype:'grid',
        store: store,
        id:'grid1',
        hidden:true,

        columnLines: true,
        columns: [{
            text     : 'Company',
            locked   : true,
            flex:1,
            width    : 200,
            sortable : false,
            dataIndex: 'company',
renderer : function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
            metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
            return value;
        }

        },{
            text     : 'Price',
            width    : 125,
            locked:true,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : 'usMoney',
            dataIndex: 'price',

        },{
            text     : 'Change',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,

            dataIndex: 'change',
            renderer : function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
            metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';

            return value;
        }

        },{
            text     : '% Change',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : pctChange,
            dataIndex: 'pctChange',

        },{
            text     : 'Last Updated',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        }],
        bbar: {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                pageSize: 10,
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true,
                plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager()
            },
        height: 0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
        title: '<center>Genus</center>',

        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        }
    };

    var grid2 = {
        xtype:'grid',
        store: store,
        id:'grid2',
        hidden:true,
        style: 'border: solid Red 2px',

        columnLines: true,
        columns: [{
            text     : 'Company',
            locked   : true,
            flex:1,
            width    : 200,
            sortable : false,
            dataIndex: 'company',
renderer : function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
            metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
            return value;
        }

        },{
            text     : 'Price',
            width    : 125,
            locked:true,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : 'usMoney',
            dataIndex: 'price',

        },{
            text     : 'Change',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,

            dataIndex: 'change',
            renderer : function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
            metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';

            return value;
        }

        },{
            text     : '% Change',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : pctChange,
            dataIndex: 'pctChange',

        },{
            text     : 'Last Updated',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        }],
        bbar: {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                pageSize: 10,
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true,
                plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager()
            },
       height: 0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
        title: '<center>Family</center>',

        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        }
    };
    var grid3 = {
        xtype:'grid',
        store: store,
        id:'grid3',

        style: 'border: solid Red 2px',


        columnLines: true,
        columns: [{
            text     : 'Company',
            locked   : true,
            flex:1,
            width    : 200,
            sortable : false,
            dataIndex: 'company',
renderer : function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
            metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
            return value;
        }

        },{
            text     : 'Price',
            width    : 125,
            locked:true,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : 'usMoney',
            dataIndex: 'price',

        },{
            text     : 'Change',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,

            dataIndex: 'change',
            renderer : function (value, metaData, record, row, col, store, gridView) {
            metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';

            return value;
        }

        },{
            text     : '% Change',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : pctChange,
            dataIndex: 'pctChange',

        },{
            text     : 'Last Updated',
            width    : 555,
            sortable : true,
            renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
            dataIndex: 'lastChange'
        }],

        height: 0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.5*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    bbar: {
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                pageSize: 10,
                store: store,
                displayInfo: true,
                plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager()
            },
        title: '<center>Phylum</center>',
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        }
    };

var panel1= {
xtype:'panel',
layout:'vbox',
width:0.15*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
height: 0.96*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
title:'panel1',
items:[{
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Genus',
    id:'button1',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.14*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,


    handler:function(button)
    {
        /*Ext.getCmp('grid2').show();*/

        button.up('#main').down('#grid2').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#grid3').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#grid1').show();
    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Family',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.14*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
     handler:function(button)
    {
        /*Ext.getCmp('grid2').show();*/

        button.up('#main').down('#grid1').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#grid3').hide();
         button.up('#main').down('#grid2').show();
    }
        },
        {
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Phylum',
    height:0.05*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    width:0.14*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
     handler:function(button)
    {
        /*Ext.getCmp('grid2').show();*/

        button.up('#main').down('#grid1').hide();
        button.up('#main').down('#grid2').hide();
         button.up('#main').down('#grid3').show();
    }
        }
        ]
};
var panel2= {
    id:'panel2',
    xtype:'panel',
     bodyStyle: 'padding: 120px;',
width:0.84*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
height: 0.96*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
/*title:'panel2',*/
layout:'vbox',
closable:true,
closeAction:'hide',
items:[grid1,grid2,grid3]
};
var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    id:'main',
    title: 'Results',
    layout:'hbox',
    width:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
    height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [panel1,panel2]
});


});
</script>
  </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess [`Ext.tab.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel) is what you looking for, with your two grids as its items. You can align tab panel header any way you like with `headerPosition` or hide  it and add custom toolbar.

As alternative solution you can add [`Ext.toolbar.Toolbar`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar) with buttons and add logic on your own.

[Simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15pn) to illustrate how you can do it, use it as base.

Comment: @sergey_novikov Thanks.....I checked ,there is an option called tab position in extjs 4 tab panel....when i set tab position to 'left',all tab come vertical ie. the corresponding tab header is read bottom to up,how to make tab heading horizontal?

Comment: @Prateek Its not available out of the box, you have to overrite `Ext.tab.Bar` - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/Bar2.html#Ext-tab-Bar

Comment: @Sergey_Novikov
I have edited the code that i was working on.....Now the problem is.....1.On clicking on any button for the first time,it takes time for corresponding grid to show up....so how can i reduce that or modify the code to make it look good.....2. The side toolbar containing three buttons.....How can i improve the look and feel of that side toolbar?

Comment: @Prateek Honestly 1. I dont know why it takes any notable time to render, I can offer you to add loading mask with `.setLoading(true)` on your grids container (on `beforerender` or so) and `setLoading(false)` when everything is ready (on `afterrender` or store `load` if you use remote data source or any other event according to your app logic). 2. Im not designer and I use sligtly modified Neptune theme, so I just can offer you to look at ExtJS theming topic - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/theming

Comment: @Sergey_Novikov could you please help me with two more things?.......1.How to add feature of pagination to my grids?......2.I want my grid to be closable.....there should be a close button on top right corner of grid that closes it....so how to make my grid closable?

Comment: @Prateek 1. Look at `Ext.toolbar.Paging` - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Paging 2. Use `closable` property and `closeAction` - http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-closable